# Is this a consecutive clause? Or an objektsatz?

Tags: grammar-identification, subordinate-clause

> Der Typ verriet damit eine gewisse Professionalität, und im
> Allgemeinen war es so, ***dass die Chance auf einen guten Ausgang bei
> einem professionellen Täter höher war***;...

So I think you can have a consecutivsatz only with *dass* (without so+adverb/adjektiv in the previous clause) and I also think this could be an objektsatz having to do with es or so in the previous clause maybe?

Comment: https://kobra.uni-kassel.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/2013100744110/zgl_2006_027.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y 
Here, it is classified as "adverb" in a sentence like yours. So it is not part of a subordinating conjunction. It happens to appear with "dass" like "so, dass" and "sodass" does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Konsekutivsatz is a dependent clause that contains a result of the main clause.

> Er war so krank, dass er nicht arbeiten konnte. *(He was so ill that he could not work.)*

I don't see that in your example, so wouldn't call it a consecutive clause.

The function of "so, dass ..." in the sentence is that of a predicative (so not an Objektsatz either):

> Im Allgemeinen war es heiß.
> *("Es" is the subject, "heiß" is an adjective predicative)*

> Im Allgemeinen war es so, dass die Chance [...] höher war.

I would call it a [Prädikativsatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativsatz). In a narrower sense, *so* is the predicative and the *dass* clause is a defining supplement for *so*.

Comment: What part of speech is "so" here? An adverb? And apart from that, is it a Korrelat? In my book definition, "so" is not counted to the Korrelate. The DWDS definition to that is very confusing as well. "so" is not a particle of degree here, right? My Duden does not help me out here either, it only knows the consecutive subjunction with the particle of degree. Any help?

Comment: I would call "so" a Korrelat here, yes. A Korrelat that isn't a pronoun but stands in for an adjective like a pronoun stands in for a noun.  But I can't cite a source for that, I might be wrong. In the sentence, it clearly has the function of a predicative.

Comment: "so" seems to be a really complicated word.

Comment: I may have not understood correctly since im not that good at grammar but are you saying that the dass clause is an Attributsatz for `so`?

Comment: @HalvarF This could be interesting: https://kobra.uni-kassel.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/2013100744110/zgl_2006_027.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y   It addresses the difficulty of categorizing "so".